# How to change the message app icon

Tags: messages, icon

The phone icon and the message icon are both green. This is poor design. How can I change the icon, or at least the color of the icon?

Comment: The WhatsApp icon is also the same green - perhaps it is meant as an indicator of a communication capability but that does not make it poor design. You might not like it but that is your choice.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but you didn't answer the question. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, you can't change the icon color for Messages or WhatsApp.  That's the color those company's made them and they didn't provide a way to change the color.

This could change in the future and you can contact those companies to request they add that ability.